# What values of $a$ and $b$ will make this function differentiable $x=-3$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What values of $a$ and $b$ will make this function differentiable at $x=-3$?
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
ax^2-8x+41 & \text{if } x \leq -3 \\
bx+5 & \text{if } x>-3\\
\end{cases}$$

k so i found the derivatives at $x=-3$:
$$-6a -8=b$$
now i have 2 variables and i have no idea how to solve for that? what should i do from this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need $f(x)$ to be continuous at $-3$, that is, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3} f(x) = f(-3)$.

ADDED: For the right-sided limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^+} (bx+5) = -3b+5$. For the left-sided limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^-} (ax^2-8x+41) = 9a+65$. It is clear that $f(-3) = 9a+65$. So equating all these gives $9a+65=-3b+5$.

Comment: yes, but how do i do that with my current equation of -6a-8=b?

Comment: for each equation separately or the combined -6a-8=b?

Comment: Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^+} f(x)$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3^-} f(x)$, and $f(-3)$, and then equate all of them. That should give $9a+65=-3b+5$. Together with $-6a-8=b$, you should be able to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: so that would yield a=4 and b=-32?

Comment: yes i will but i am still unsure on how you arrived at 9a +65=-3b+5